# Mahalanobis Distance Matching

Tags: causality, matching

When doing Mahalanobis matching to improve covariate balance for causual inference, how come if the treated units aren't subsampled only the control covariance matrix is used $S_c$ as opposed to the pool covariance matrix?

MD = $ \sqrt{(x_t-x_c)'S_c^{-1}(x_t-x_c)}$